# Add view checkbox with same class (Switchery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, switchery

I tried to add into my website view checkboxes with js-switch class.
This code use Switchery module.
I wrote my example below:

```
<pre><code>http://codepen.io/Rootka/pen/bpvbNy</code></pre>
```

**How to add a view checkboxes with same class - e.g. "js-switch"?**

Comment: you have to use `querySelectorAll` then you will get an array of element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `querySelectorAll()` you can do the following to active your switches:

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch');
for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++ ){
    new Switchery(elem[i], {className:"switchery"});
}
```

Your now working codepen: http://codepen.io/kbkb/pen/dMmbvK

Comment: this code doesn't work in my case. Only the first one checkbox looks like i want (style from Switchery module). I put your code into function and i called it and it something wrong with this...